# How to add an index to set members and convert members to tuple?

Tags: python

I want to set an index for my set elements. For example, if my set was equal to:

```
A = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

I want to convert this to:

```
B = {('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 4)}
```

is there any way in Python to do this?

Comment: Do you know set in Python is unorder? Meaning the order is not guaranteed

Comment: ```c,4```? Shouldn't it be ```d,3?```: ```B=sorted({(j,i) for i,j in enumerate(A)},key= lambda x: x[1])```

Comment: @DanielHao I just wanted to assign some different integers for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B = {(elem, idx) for idx, elem in enumerate(A)}
```

Order is not defined for sets, so if you need order, a set is not the right data structure.

Comment: I just wanted to assign some different integers for them I did not want to order them.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the index as the first element of the tuples:

```
set(enumerate(A))
# {(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')}
```

This will return as your output, the index as the second item of the tuples:

```
set(zip(A, range(len(A)))
# {('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3)}
```

Comment: Why are you doing ```set(enumerate(A))``` and ```zip()```? ```enumerate``` it self returns a tuple with the counter and the element

Comment: The output type is set right?. Question wants to convert set of characters to set of tuples

Comment: If you want to work with `zip`, I would prefer `set(zip(A, range(len(A))))`... though I prefer comprehension :)

Comment: Yeah thats more general

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
B=sorted({(j,i) for i,j in enumerate(A)},key= lambda x: x[1])
```